# Wordpress Search PDF documents without plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, ocr

I know there are a lot of plugins out there that allow this functionality, but I would like to program a theme function to allow for the built-in WordPress search to be able to list OCR PDF's that match the search query in the list of search results. I am unable to find a programmatic solution for this, only plug-in's.

Does anyone know of an existing filter or theme function that would allow this to happen or is a plugin my only option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add a PDF post type and add the details of them in there. If you want to simply search titles that would be easy. If you want to search inside the pdf that is not going to happen without extra coding. So a plan B would be to copy and paste the text of the pfd into your custom post type and wordpress can search that instead and still find the relevant pdf. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: It makes total sense and I thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, that's too much work for the client! I need a way to program the search itself to be able to search within PDF documents.

Comment: WordPress search wont do that unfortunately - its barely any good at searching WordPress data let alone within a pdf :) You really will have to go down a third party plugin / code route on this one I am afraid.